# Is using Parcelable the right way to send data between applications?

Tags: android, marshalling, unmarshalling, parcelable, multiple-processes

I am trying to understand how to communicate between applications in Android - not just between `Activity` instances.

I set up a 'client' that sends a Messenger obj to a Service (in the `Intent` sent to the service); the service creates a `Message` obj and sends it back to the 'client' using `messenger.send(message)`. This works fine until I try to use the Message.obj to hold an object.

I created my own `Parcelable` class `MyParcelable` in the service and put it into the message. All works until the message is unmarshalled in the 'client'. The unmarshall fails because the 'client' has no access to the `MyParcelable` class. That's obvious - they are in different packages (say `com.whatever.myclient` and `com.whatever.myserver`). Is this completely the wrong way to go about this?

I have also tried creating a `Parcel` and sending that (both applications would thereby have access to the class) - but `Parcel` is not `Parcelable`. I have read about class loaders being used but do not understand how separate class loaders in separate applications (processes, if I understand Android architecture in that regard). That is, how can one class loader be 'taught' about a class that exists in the other class loader? It certainly seems like there should be an obvious 'this is how you do it' but I have not seen it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot unmarshall a class at a process that has no knowledge of this class (as you already correctly pointed out). If you want `MyParcelable` to be sent to your `Service`, then you need to include `MyParcelable` in the `Service` at build, **and** include the right `ClassLoader` to be used when unmarshalling, because unmarshalling is done by a system thread, which doesn't know what `MyParcelable` is even if you included it at compile time.

*EDIT*:

> (a) include MyParcelable into 2 different pkgs and have them be seen
>   as the same class

Make a library of your common classes and include it in both applications (the application and the `Service`). You can either mark it as an Android library (in Eclipse this is right under the project's Android properties) or export it as a JAR and import it in both apps. It's always a good idea to have *independent* classes in a library instead of putting them in the apps directly. This way you can reuse them on other projects ;)

> (2) include the right ClassLoader (where do I get the right class
>   loader from, for example)

You can get your `ClassLoader` from the current thread when you're executing your code. Obviously this `ClassLoader` knows about your classes because it's executing your code ;) For example in `Activity#onCreate()`, you can do `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader()`. Since your `MyParcelable` class is also included on the `Service`, you can do the same to get a valid `ClassLoader` to unmarshall.

Another solution for IPC is to define an [AIDL interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) so you don't have to implement `Parcelable`.

Comment: Hey m0skit0, you should expand this a bit.  I was going to answer, but you have it exactly right.  A little more explanation would just make it clearer.  Parcelables only work if the ClassLoaders marshalling and unmarshalling the data have identical copies of the Parcelable class...

Comment: Sounds good but I have no idea how to do either (a) include MyParcelable into 2 different pkgs and have them be seen as the same class or (2) include the right ClassLoader (where do I get the right class loader from, for example). Thanks for your answer but you're about 2 levels of expertise above my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use a persistence layer somewhere ( i use cloud apis ) you could  run a service in a separate process and bind to the service the respective apps that need the shared value-holder type object data. the service would be where you construct and get the obj values on behalf of connecting ( binding ) apps.

Comment: These are both very good suggestions and I will definitely keep them close by as I proceed. I am at this point mainly trying to get a grasp on the Parcelable and class loader concepts in hopes that I will understand them enough to be able to use them appropriately. Thanks much for your answer.

Comment: know the android fundamentals and activity lifecycle . that may be more important than CL concepts. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Comment: imo - inter app, the easiest would be using 'intent-extra' fields and a i guess a chooser which would allow selection of the target app .

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the 'easy way' I was looking for. You can put a Bundle into the Message.obj field. Bundle is Parcelable so can be transported between client and server. There's no issue of the server not knowing what class it's receiving as Bundle is 'built into' Android Java. And Bundle can apparently include 'sub-Bundles' with in. This is simpler than having to deal with ensuring both parties know the definition of a user-defined class. Thanks for the answers above - I certainly appreciated the info!