# Parcelable Object return BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("name")

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, parcelable, badparcelableexception

I have a problem when I write pracelable object and receive from another application that I wrote.
Everytime when I tried to get the object it always turned out to be BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling.

I've been looking around and wonder if it turned out bad when I send to another application.
Or it's simply I had error in my codes.

Please tell me where did I go wrong.

**my sending lines:**

```
ParcelableObject myObject = new ParcelableObject();
myObject = new ParcelableObject(result_name, resut_lv, result_race, 
    result_job, result_nation, result_guild, result_mission);
intent.putExtra("ACTION_DATA_TRANSFER", myObject);
intent.setClassName(target_app, target_app+".ReceiveMain");
startActivity(intent);
```

**my receive lines:**

```
ParcelableObject myObject = new ParcelableObject();
myObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ACTION_DATA_TRANSFER"); //always crashed at this line

if (getIntent().hasExtra("ACTION_DATA_TRANSFER")) {
    Log.w("****CHECKING****", myObject.getName());
    item1.setText("The Character's name is: " + myObject.getName());
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is not data passed yet", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**my ParcelableObject class:**

```
private String name;
private int lv;
private String race;
private String job;
private String nation;
private String guild;
public String mission;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setLv(int lv) {
    this.lv = lv;
}

public void setRace(String race) {
    this.race = race;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

public void setNation(String nation) {
    this.nation = nation;
}

public void setGuild(String guild) {
    this.guild = guild;
}

public void setMission(String mission) {
    this.mission = mission;
}

public ParcelableObject(String name, int lv, String race, String job, String
     nation, String guild, String mission) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.name = name;
    this.lv = lv;
    this.race = race;
    this.job = job;
    this.nation = nation;
    this.guild = guild;
    this.mission = mission;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getLv() {
    return lv;
}

public String getRace() {
    return race;
}

public String getJob() {
    return job;
}

public String getNation() {
    return nation;
}

public String getGuild() {
    return guild;
}

public String getMission() {
    return mission;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w("****PO CHECKING****", "describeContents called");
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w("****PO CHECKING****", "writeToParcel called");
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(job);
    dest.writeInt(lv);
    dest.writeString(race);
    dest.writeString(guild);
    dest.writeString(nation);       
    dest.writeString(mission);
}

public ParcelableObject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    Log.i("**check if exist**", "start parcel");
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableObject> CREATOR = 
    new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableObject>() {

    @Override
    public ParcelableObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("checking out", "createFromParcel");
        ParcelableObject pObject = new ParcelableObject();
        pObject.name = in.readString();
        pObject.job = in.readString();
        pObject.lv = in.readInt();
        pObject.race = in.readString();
        pObject.guild = in.readString();
        pObject.nation = in.readString();
        pObject.mission = in.readString();

        return pObject;
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelableObject[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ParcelableObject[size];
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**
To clarify before some people think I am a lazy noob, I have been looking for answer to solve the cause for this but without any luck.  I looked up many people's code and tested out many times but still can't get my app right.  So that is why I am here to ask help.  If some people still think I am a lazy noob, I guess I am too lazy for some people to draw that conclusion.  I should reconsider of my action again.

My situation is:

I wrote 2 apps and one is sending a parcelable object to another application.  First app it's working correctly to send the object to another.  However, as the second app receive it, it goes wrong and gives out the `BadParcelableException` as I run the process.  I am not using bundle because I saw many examples that it is not necessary to do so.  If I have been wrong please correct me.

Comment: first define crash(with full stacktrace) ... `pObject = in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());` <= seriously ? you wana read same object in reading the object method?

Comment: that is the line I have been testing. Even without that line, app still has the same exception.

Comment: Besides I am new to this, I can't see my problem yet.  That's why I come here to ask for help.  am I doing something wrong even just asking question?

Comment: if you minify the apk this maybe the cause ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274974/android-badparcelableexception-only-with-signed-apk/19275783#19275783

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am not minify the apk.  I just don't understand where is my problem.

Comment: Are you sure that should work? look at the doc for the exception it says: "The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists." doesnt that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that related to this topic...
[Is using Parcelable the right way to send data between applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606460/is-using-parcelable-the-right-way-to-send-data-between-applications)

Thank you all for the comments from above....

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my case by using `serializable` instead of `Parcelable`.

but in your case here try parsing the object like this

```
myObject = (ParcelableObject)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ACTION_DATA_TRANSFER");
```

Comment: I know how to do it as `serializeable` however I noticed that `parcelable` is working faster than `serializeable` so that I why I want to work as `parcelable`.  Today I saw a document said that in order to do as `parcelable` need to go through service and with the help of ADIL in order to make this possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am appreciated with all your helps =)